# Why MediaPlayer constructor is undefined?

Tags: android, media-player, undefined

I'm trying to set my mediaplayer to sound in my RAW folder. All examples says that I need set Context and resource id to sound file, like this:

```
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(this, R.raw.sound);
```

Looks simple, but when I do that Eclipse shows me error:

```
The constructor MediaPlayer(Main, int) is undefined
```

Could you please explain why this happens?

Comment: Does your class extend from Activity or Service?  Basically, are you sure it's a Context?

Comment: Yes, I do it in Main class which extends Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because MediaPlayer only has a default constructor.

Do this instead:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
```